# How can I expand this code? Finding the number of consonants,words,spaces,and special characters

Tags: java

How can I expand this code. I can already find all the vowels.

I need to add on to it to also print the number of consonants,words,spaces,and special characters.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class CountVowels
 {

public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
       BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)           );
       System.out.println("Enter the String:"                                            );
       String text = bf.readLine(                                                        );
       int count = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
       char c = text.charAt(i);
       if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u')
      {
       count++;
      }
      }
       System.out.println("There are" + " " + count + " " + "vowels"                      );
}
}
```

Here is the code I have so far.

EDIT: When I mean special characters I mean Shift + 1-0.

Comment: When you say "Shift + 1-0", what do you mean by that?  Do you mean ... digits?  Cos they are not what people normally call "special".

Comment: Consider properly indending your code -- this will make it **much** easier to reason through. I.e., indent everything inside { } by 3 spaces.

Comment: Tagged as "homework" - as a recommendation that the Question should be treated as if it was homework, and that Answers should be in the form of hints and advice, not fully working solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a typical rookie mistake: you're putting too much stuff into your main method.

Create a method that takes in a String and counts vowels, another for consonants, another for spaces, special characters, words, etc.

Here's one way to do it.  The interface is optional; consider it a learning experience.

```
public interface TextCounter {
    int countVowels(String s);
    // etc. - you get the idea.
}
```

And now your implementation:

```
public class TextCounterImpl implements TextCounter {
    public int countVowels(String s) {
        int numVowels = 0;
        if ((s != null) && (s.trim().length() > 0) {
            s = s.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                // What about the "sometimes 'y'" rule?
                if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u')) {
                    ++numVowels;
                }
            }
        }
        return numVowels;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class called LineParser which will parse through the string. It is always a good practice to access the variable using get and set methods.

```
class LineParser {

    public int numberOfVowels;
    public int numberOfConsonents;
    public int numberOfSpaces;
    public int numberOfSpecialChars;
    public int numberOfWords;
    public int numberOfDigits;

    public LineParser(String str)   {
       ProcessStr(str);
    }

    //Parses a string to count number of vowels, consonents, spaces, 
    //special characters and words,
    //Treates non letter chars as word terminators.
    //So London2Paris contains 2 words. 
    private void ProcessStr(String str) {

        boolean wordend = false;
        char[] word = new char[str.length()];
        int wordIndex = 0;

        for (char c : str.toCharArray()){           
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)){
                if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                        word[wordIndex++] = c;
                        c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
                        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'){
                           numberOfVowels ++;
                        }
                        else {
                           numberOfConsonents ++;
                        }
                 }
                 else {
                    numberOfDigits++;
                    wordend = true;
                 }
            } 
            else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                numberOfSpaces ++;
                wordend = true;
             } 
             else {             
                 numberOfSpecialChars ++;
                         wordend = true;
             }

             if (wordend == true && wordIndex > 0){
                 numberOfWords ++;
                 wordIndex = 0;
                 wordend = false;
             }
        }       
        wordend = true; 
        if (wordend == true && wordIndex > 0){
            numberOfWords ++;
        }
    }
}
```

This class can used from your main function like this

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the String:");
    String text = bf.readLine();
    LineParser parser = new LineParser(text);

    System.out.println("There are" + " " + parser.numberOfVowels + " " + "vowels");
    System.out.println("There are" + " " + parser.numberOfConsonents + " " + "Consonents");
    System.out.println("There are" + " " + parser.numberOfSpaces + " " + "Spaces");
    System.out.println("There are" + " " + parser.numberOfSpecialChars + " " + "SpecialChars");
    System.out.println("There are" + " " + parser.numberOfWords + " " + "Words");
}
```